# Is there a way to keep Visual Studio from locking image files that you set at design time (ie, background images)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, design-time

I have been working in VB.NET for about a year now (upgrading old VB6 projects, ugh), and a lot of my work involves placing controls on background images to simulate an HMI (Human-Machine Interface). A huge part of this is editing the background of the form (as well as other Image controls). My issue with VS is that when I set an image to a control/form, VS locks the image file. When I need to adjust my image, after test fitting it on the form, I am forced to restart VS to release the lock and overwrite the image file.

I've searched Google and found a mention of an issue like this in VS2005, so it has been a problem for a while now. I wasn't able to find a setting to change in VS and there really wasn't much help from the internet either, so I'll post my solution here.

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was pretty simple (in my case) and I got the idea from this [blog](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/07/load-images-without-locking-their-files-in-c/):

Even at design time VS executes some of the form/control code when you load the control/form (ie, `OnLoad, Paint`, etc), so I created an simple override to the Image property to alter how the image was loaded. Obviously I had a class derived from `Windows.Forms` to work with:

```
Public Class SGBase 
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    ' Irrelevent code...
    ' ...
    Public Overrides Property BackgroundImage As Image
        Get
            Return MyBase.BackgroundImage
        End Get
        Set(value As Image)
            If MyBase.BackgroundImage IsNot Nothing Then MyBase.BackgroundImage.Dispose()
                MyBase.BackgroundImage = New Bitmap(value)
            End Using
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The underlying issue is that when you load an image into a form/control, the VS IDE locks the file and sets it to the `BackgroundImage` reference. My solution utilizes the `Using` statement to prevent file lock and I make sure to properly dispose of and create a new instance. VS runs this code at design time every time you refresh/change the form.

VOILA!

Comment: Skip the `Using bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(value)` block. You never use the `bm` variable anywhere so it's just a waste of resources to create yet another image. If you want to dispose the original image just do: `Using value` (yes, it's that short).

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way would be to choose 'Project Resource File' in the 'select resource' dialogue instead of choosing local resource. this way VS creates a duplicate of your file in the 'Resources' folder and u can open it from that folder with other software. Photoshop for example.
Another advantage of using this method is that u can ship all the required resources with your project source for later edits.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. In my specific case the images are shipped with the software and must be editable on the fly. They are loaded every time the form loads (upgrading 15yo VB6 projects sucks). I still can't figure out why VS would need to lock the files like that though....